# can we retrieve the geo-localization info from the client browser from the $_SERVER in php?

Tags: php, localization, geolocation, ip-geolocation

some modern browser have no the possibility to active(or not) the geolocalization.
so, when it is activate, how can we retrive it from php server like in the $_SERVER variable ?

is there any special constant for localisation like the user-agent ?

thanks for help

Comment: [Have a look, and find out](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that anything getting generated from the client end can be spoofed. The `$_SERVER` or the `get_browser()` functions do not gather geolocation as far as I know.

One thing you could do with HTML is to use the [GeoLocation API](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html) `navigator.geolocation` to extract some information required and send it across to a server script using an `async ajax`call..

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes. You get the IP with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. This won't tell you anything though without an IP lookup API like MaxMind's GeoIP databases.